# Give "x" on this.x a variable value when passing objects to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, scope

I have seen in multiple questions on Stackoverflow, that I can pass a variable to a this keyword:

```
name = "world";
alert("Hello " + this.name);
```

However, I am struggling with the following code:

```
$('.test').click(function() {
    var data = $(this).data();
    var type = data.type;

    $('#world-map-geo1').empty();

    $.getJSON('json/geoCountries-' + site + '.json', function (pushArray) {
        var countryData = [];
        console.log(type);
        $.each(pushArray, function() {
            // Following line doesn't make what I expect.
            countryData[this.countryIsoCode] = this.type;
            // alert(this.type)
        });
        console.log(countryData);
    });
});
```

The function is executed once I click a li, f.i.:

```
<li class="test" data-type="sessions">Sessions</li>
```

I am getting undefined values, as this.type seems not being transformed as this.sessions. However, if I manually change this.type to this.sessions, it works correctly.

I know it is not a problem of variable scope, as if I replace this.type for only type, I get "sessions" on every array object.

I am totally sure, that the problem is my limited knowledge on jquery and how this keyword works for this particular approach, as althought I have not tried it, I believe that if I have an object named type inside my json, this.type would take those values instead of those in this.sessions.

Comment: In general, `this` refers to whoever calls the function. So your first `this` is the element that was clicked on, but the second `this` inside `getJSON()` refers to the inner function. If you want to refer to the outer `this` in your inner function, you need to pass it as a variable.

Comment: where does 'countryIsoCode' come from..? and i guess you could directly use 'type' instead of this.type in your inner function..!

Comment: `name = "world";` creates (in non-strict mode) a global variable, which is bad. Then, if `this` has not been set, it will be `window` (in non-strict mode). Therefore, `this.name` will be like `window.name` and you will get your value. But don't do that.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us your JSON (or preferably a representative sample of it). And why are you assigning `data.type` to a variable and then doing nothing with it (besides printing it to the console)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all this line:

```
var type = data.type;
```

should probably be

```
this.type = data.type;
```

In your code above 'this' will refer to $('.test'), i.e. the jQuery object created using the dom element with the class 'test'.

For the array you have later on, you will need to ensure that the inner function's scope is aware of its parent 'this' context. This is usually done by binding the inner function to its parent.

It would look something like this

```
$.method = func(){}.bind(this);
```

Also, regarding 
var countryData = []; AND countryData[this.countryIsoCode] = this.type;

You will probably need to make countryData into an object so that

```
var countryData = {};
```

I would suggest reading up on the differences between arrays and objects, i.e. [] vs {}.